# Django rest framework пагинациая в связанной модели

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

Здравствуйте.

Хочу сделать пагинацию в связанной модели, а именно, хочу чтобы при обращении к модели `Event`, я получал строго определённое количество экземпляров модели  `Message`, и чтобы я этим количеством мог управлять.

```
class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ('name', 'flag', 'cropping')

class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    team = TeamSerializer()
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ('msg_type', 'team', 'team_type', 'user', 'timestamp', 'human_timestamp', 'message')


class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    event_messages = MessageSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('status', 'name', 'home_team', 'away_team', 'event_messages')
```

На изображении это поле называется `event_messages`, и мне нужно как-то ограничить его выдачу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Лучше так не делать, это обсуждалось на гитхабе drf. В итоге, в той теме накидали костылей (что-то не могу найти ссылку), но все время обнаруживаются проблемы. 
Сделайте отдельный ресурс (api url) для event_messages типа

```
/event/{id}/messages
```

Answer (score 0):

В итоге сделал так:

```
from rest_framework import serializers, pagination

    class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        messages = serializers.SerializerMethodField('event_messages')

        def event_messages(self, obj):
            messages = Message.objects.filter(event=obj)
            paginator = pagination.PageNumberPagination()
            page = paginator.paginate_queryset(messages, self.context['request'])
            serializer = MessageSerializer(page, many=True, context={'request': self.context['request']})
            return serializer.data

        class Meta:
            model = Event
            fields = ('status', 'name', 'home_team', 'away_team', 'messages')
```

а в `settings.py` добавил:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 5
}
```

Работает при `RetrieveAPIView` (`DetailView`), а запрос отправляется так: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/events/1/?page=1`.